# Emails to root go to root@localhost and BCC my aliased address

Tags: 14.04, root, email, postfix

I've configured postfix to send through my gmail account.  My /etc/aliases looks like this:

```
postmaster:    root
root:   my-email-address@gmail.com
```

When I test this using the following:

```
echo test | mail -s "test message" root
```

I receive the email in my gmail account as sent to root@localhost with my gmail account BCC'd.

I'd like to have it sent directly to my gmail account and not to the root@localhost.

What am I missing?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

Applying the suggested virtual mapping I can see the effects at the BCC level but it is still BCC'ing rather than sending root email directly to the intended email address.

The main.cf change made is:

```
virtual_alias_domains = uberserver uberserver.home my-registered-domain.net
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

And the /etc/postfix/virtual change:

```
root@uberserver.home    my-email-addr+root@gmail.com
root@mail.my-registered-domain.net    my-email-addr+rootmah@gmail.com
root@my-registered-domain.net my-email-addr+rootah@gmail.com
```

(I did this so that I could see different gmail recipients depending on the recipient postfix originally saw.)

Note that I also had to run postmap... then I re-ran the test.

Here's an example of the test email received in gmail:

```
Bcc: my-email-addr+root@gmail.com
Return-Path: <my-email-addr@gmail.com>
Received: from uberserver.home (pool-xxx-xx-xxx-xx.someplace.fios.verizon.net. [xxx.xx.xxx.xx])
        by smtp.gmail.com with ESMTPSA id v78sm25438329qge.25.2016.01.09.09.00.25
        for <my-email-addr+root@gmail.com>
        (version=TLS1_2 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128);
        Sat, 09 Jan 2016 09:00:25 -0800 (PST)
From: Scott Hamilton <my-email-addr@gmail.com>
X-Google-Original-From: scott@uberserver.home (Scott Hamilton)
Received: by uberserver.home (Postfix, from userid 1000)
    id A47B44809C5; Sat,  9 Jan 2016 12:01:02 -0500 (EST)
Subject: test message
To: <root@uberserver.home>
X-Mailer: mail (GNU Mailutils 2.99.98)
Message-Id: <20160109170102.A47B44809C5@uberserver.home>
Date: Sat,  9 Jan 2016 12:01:02 -0500 (EST)

test
```

Answer (score 1):

The method you describe is merely used for aliasing non existing mailboxes, I do not know if this behavior can be tweaked to do it differently.
However you can accomplish what you want by editing `/etc/postfix/main.cf` and adding two lines:

```
virtual_alias_domains = mydomain.com myanotherdomain.com
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

then edit (or create) `/etc/postfix/virtual` and add:

```
contact@mydomain.com myself@gmail.com
```

after saving execute the command `sudo service postfix reload`

(See also: [here](http://www.binarytides.com/postfix-mail-forwarding-debian/))

Comment: Thanks - and thanks for the link as it informed me of the need to run postmap as an additional step.  I updated my original post with more details as this is still not quite functioning how I'd like.  I also thought maybe I needed to remove the /etc/aliases and root/.forward attempts I had made but these made no difference when I removed them and restarted postfix (and ran newaliases).

Comment: You're welcome. When a solution provides you with a correct answer you can confirm this by clicked the accept button so others can quickly see the answer worked for the questioner.
see also: http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Well, it's not quite resolved/answered yet. :)  I'm still trying to get the emails set without the BCC directly to the gmail account.